# what does "generate method stub" mean in c#?

Tags: visual-studio, code-generation

I'm trying to call a function, and VS gives me an error (red underline), and i have the option to "generate method stub". What is this?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcz8b6zc(VS.80).aspx, check out the MSDN article for more info

Comment: I'm not sure why people are voting to close this as too localized - it is a problem that lots of people have encountered at one time or another in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that you're trying to call the function incorrectly; check to make sure you've spelled the method name correctly, and that you're passing it the proper number and types of arguments.

Answer (score 4):

The generate method stub will generate you a method which looks exactly like you've written it, with the same parameters. Probably are getting this error because you've misspelled the method or because it is in a different namespace.

Answer (score 3):

It means you typed a wrong signature, so VS assumes this method doesn't exist. By using the shortcut VS can help you create the method as a stub (i.e. the signature, then you have to fill out the implementation).

Answer (score 0):

ahh I had

```
method(button.Tag);
```

and a declaration of

```
void method(int tag)
```

so i fixed it with

```
method(int.Parse(button.Tag.toString()));
```

i tried that before, but I forgot to put "toString", since I thought it was already an int... stupid little mistake. thx guys